# Update (save & delete) relationship without using $related->get();

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I'm using [codeigniter 2.1.4](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) & [datamapper orm](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/). I know how to [save relations](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/save.html#Relationship) to an object and I know how to [delete them](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/delete.html#Relationship).

In this case I have a many-to-many relation, which I want to update with new values from a form. Now I can use this to save them which works just fine:

```
$ousergroupright = new Usergroupright;
$usergrouprights = $ousergroupright->where_in('id', $this->input->post('usergrouprights'))->get();

$ousergroup = new Usergroup;
$ousergroup->get_by_id($id);
$ousergroup->save($usergrouprights->all);
```

But this doesn't delete the records I "unchecked" in my form. I need to delete the objects I don't want related anymore. What would be the best way to do this (without using custom queries)?

A query like above with `$ousergroup->where_not_in()` before saving seems overkill to me (why query database and build objects *just* to delete a relation?):

```
$ousergroupright = new Usergroupright;
$usergrouprights = $ousergroupright->where_not_in('id', $this->input->post('usergrouprights'))->get();

$ousergroup = new Usergroup;
$ousergroup->get_by_id($id);
$ousergroup->delete($usergrouprights->all);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to delete the objects you don't want related anymore without the need to query a database and build objects just to delete a relation. You can use the utility function query a run a custom SQL to delete all the unrelated objects WITHOUT needing to perform a database query, something like:

```
// Create usergroup object
$u = new Usergroup();

// your custom SQL query to delete the unrelated objects
$sql = "delete from usergrouprights where usergroup.id = ? and id usergrouprights.id not in (?)";

// Binding values
$binds = array($idUserGroup , $listOfSelectedItens);

// Run query to populate user object with the results
$u->query($sql);
```

More about DataMapper query utility function
http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/utility.html#query

Comment: Using a custom query is a nice solution, but I would like to use the model. When I change the properties of the model, I don't want to search my application for "custom queries"...

Comment: Well, in this case, i think you could have been more specific about that in your question but okay, i can understand that you dont want to use custom queries

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marcelo, but I think my option (select all where !=...) and yours (custom queries) both aren't the solution I'm looking for. There has to be another (better) way!